# Как при удалении приложения удалить созданные приложением файлы

Tags: android, java

Доброго дня, возникла проблема следующего характера. Моё приложение по ходу работы создаёт один текстовый файл. Когда юзер удаляет приложение с телефона файлик остаётся. Подскажите пожалуйста как программно сделать так чтобы этот файлик удалялся тожже

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пишите в директорию, возвращаемую вызовом `context.getFilesDir()`. В этом случае и мусорить на устройстве не будете и при удалении приложения все эти файлы удалятся автоматически.

Небольшой пример:

```
File outputFile = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "filename");
```

Или же, ещё проще:

```
File outputFile = context.getFileStreamPath("filename");
```

И дальше пишите в `outputFile` как обычно.

Comment: а можно небольшой пример, а то так сходу не особо понятно

Comment: вот только ругается на File outputFile = new File(Context.getFilesDir(), "filename");компилятор(импорт сделал)
пишет: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getFilesDir() from the type Context
В чём проблема может быть?

Comment: Проблема в том, что вы подставили вместо контекста сам класс `Context`. А эти методы — `non-static`, о чём вам компилятор и сообщает.