# Удаление файлов приложения вместе с приложением

Tags: java, android

Каким образом сохранять файл, чтобы он удалялся вместе с приложением? Файл служит для определения авторизовался пользователь или нет. На данный момент делаю так:

```
    File f = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "UserId.xml");
    if (f.exists()) {
        Intent yesauth = new Intent(LAUNCH.this, Profile.class);
        startActivity(yesauth);
    } else {
        Intent noauth = new Intent(LAUNCH.this, Authorization.class);
        startActivity(noauth);
    }
```

Однако происходит странная вещь: при удалении приложения и его новой загрузке файл уже есть и в нём уже записано значение, а именно "1", откуда оно берётся - не могу понять, записываться туда оно должно только при авторизации.

Comment: до этого был вариант с sp, тоже ничего не удалялось при удалении приложения. текущий способ взят из этого ответа https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/332797/390915

Comment: ага, понятно. Ну может быть изменилась работа системы при удалении приложения или особенности именного этой модели/производителя

Comment: В манифесте у вас есть такое: `android:allowBackup="true"`? Это сохраняет приватные файлы приложения в гугло-аккаунте юзера и при повторной установке оттуда восстанавливает, при чём на любом аппарате если аккаунт тот же.

Comment: Действительно, это помогло, после замены на android:allowBackup="false" проблема решилась. Спасибо большое! Хотя как это работает не очень понимаю, связи с гугл аккаунтом у приложения нет никакой, в плей маркете оно не размещено